# JavaScript breaking even when I test if a variable exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

When PHP is building HTML document, I add to it a code `var myVariable = 'somedata';`, which is used by a .js file. Of course, that file's code must be prepared for that variable not being set.

Doing some tests, I see that if I don't set the variable in HTML, Firebug console reports `myVariable is not defined`, and the code breaks: everything that should be run after the call to the function that uses that variable, doesn't run at all.

Only that function requires that variable, so I want the it to nicely return instead of breaking, so I used `if(undefined === myVariable) return;`, but it didn't work. Console still reports that error, and JS still breaks.

What's the best practice for testing if a variable is defined before using it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the type of your variable instead:

```
if (typeof myVariable === "undefined")
```